# Rails DateTime Conversion and Time Comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I am having a bit of trouble with comparing times in Rails. I want to check to see if an event lies within a window, if it does, then find which, the event or window starts last and which ends first. My code is as follows.

```
startingTime = 0
endingTime = 0
time = 0

eventTimeStart = Time.parse(event.start.to_s) #Need to convert DateTime to just Time
windowTimeStart = Time.parse(application.reportStart.to_s)

eventTimeEnd = Time.parse(event.end.to_s) #Need to convert DateTime to just Time
windowTimeEnd = Time.parse(application.reportEnd.to_s)

days = 0

if((windowTimeStart > eventTimeStart) || !(eventTimeStart < windowTimeEnd))
  startingTime = windowTimeStart
  if((eventTimeStart > windowTimeEnd))
    days -= 1
   end
else
  startingTime = eventTimeStart
end

if((windowTimeEnd > eventTimeEnd) && (eventTimeEnd > windowTimeStart))
  endingTime = eventTimeEnd
else
  if((eventTimeEnd < windowTimeStart))
    days -= 1
   end
  endingTime = windowTimeEnd
end
```

I have handwritten out each case, however at runtime it seems to run different from expected. It seems as if I always get into the windowed times. Does Rails use a different approach to Times than what I'm thinking? Can you even compare times in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion Mladen.

In order to get this working, I passed all of the time objects into a method I made that converted them into minutes.

```
def self.getMin(time)
    return((time.hour*60) + time.min)
end
```

I called that on all of my checks and now it seems to work.

```
if((getMin(windowTimeStart) > getMin(eventTimeStart)) || !(getMin(eventTimeStart) < getMin(windowTimeEnd)))
  startingTime = windowTimeStart
  if((getMin(eventTimeStart) > getMin(windowTimeEnd)))
    days -= 1
   end
else
  startingTime = eventTimeStart
end
```

I'm sure there is a better way to check, however it does work now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to see whether intervals overlap or not, this simple check will do:

```
overlaps = interval_1_start < interval_2_end && interval_1_end > interval_2_start
```

I don't understand the rest of the question, but I just hope that you don't have two big loops for `event` and `application` around the code you have pasted above.